# Questions about binary serialization and deserialization

Tags: node.js, serialization, binary, buffer

I wanted to create a module that would efficiently serialize and deserialize a Buffer. So i'm asking myself several question.

**Is it a good operation to create a ES6 class with serialize and deserialize function, and dealing with bitwise operator, or do i have to work with module like concetrate or dissolve ?** Which operation is better ?

I've looked for a NPM package that would efficiently serialize and deserialize ZCL buffer and i've found something like "binary-parser" which look good, but it might be heavy because of the multiple varying byte of the ZCL cluster that i have to implement.

So **is there something that, instead of only serialize or deserialize only, will do both ?**